# Pointer dereference array index

Tags: c, pointers, initialization, undefined-behavior, pointer-arithmetic

Having this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Test { char c; } foo;

int main (void) {

   struct Test **ar;
   ar=malloc(16);
   *(ar+1) = &foo;
   ar[1]->c = 'c'; //this work
  (*(*ar+1)).c = 'c'; //this does't work

   return 0;
}
        //(**(ar+1)).c='c'; --> first case
```

Why the above works only the variant with array entry and not pointer dereference?

```
struct Test { char c; } foo;

int main (void) {

   struct Test **ar;
   ar=malloc(16);
   *ar=malloc(0);
   *(ar+1) = &foo;
   //(**(ar+1)).c='c';
   (*(*ar+1)).c='c'; // NOW IT WORKS --> second case
   printf("%c\n", (*(*ar+1)).c); //prints 'c'

   return 0;
}
```

Now even allocated 0 bytes, that doesnt matter since I just want an address provided by OS in order to have the first element initilalized

question: how does pointer arithmetic works in both cases?
As I understand the them:

1) first In order to get to lvalue of `struct Test`, the pointer goes directly from the pointed address by `ar` to the lvalue by `**ar` - `sizeof(struct Test**)`

2) in second case, the pointer does have initialized the first member `ar[0]`, so it starts here `*ar` and goes to the lvalue by `*ar` - `sizeof(struct Test*)`.

But both pointers have same size `sizeof(struct Test**) == sizeof(struct Test*)`, and therefor shouldn't be difference in arithmetic, or I am missing somehting?

Comment: See [C Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), `'*'` has higher precedence than `'+'` so what is happening with `(*(*ar+1)).c`?

Comment: Using index notation "this work" is `ar[1][0].c = 'c';` and "this doesn't work" is `ar[0][1].c = 'c'`, which doesn't work because you never set a value for `ar[0]`. In the second one you cause undefined behaviour but sometimes that manifests itself as appearing to do what you expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct Test **ar;
ar=malloc(16);
...
(*(*ar+1)).c = 'c'; //this does't work
```

Of course it does. As noted in my comment `*` has higher precedence than `+` [C Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). So what is happening in `(*(*ar+1)).c`? Look at:

```
(*ar+1)
```

which is equivalent to:

```
(ar[0] + 1)
```

Since the **type** for `ar` is a *pointer-to-pointer-to* `struct Test`,  `*ar` or `ar[0]` is type *pointer-to* `struct Test`. Then you add `+ 1` which adds `sizeof (struct Test*)` to the first pointer `ar` which is what you want.

Why does that work? Operator precedence:

```
   *ar              /* dereference ar** leaving pointer to struct Test */

  (*ar + 1)         /* advance to next pointer - applied before next dereference */

 *(*ar + 1)         /* dereference again leaving struct Test assigned to 2nd pointer */

(*(*ar + 1)).c      /* reference member 'c' of above */
```

Readability is critical when playing with multiple levels of indirection. Using index notation will help greatly. Instead of `(*(*ar + 1)).c = 'c';`, it is much cleaner to write:

```
(*ar)[1].c = 'c';
```

That conveys clearly you are dereferencing `ar` first before applying the offset of `1` and dereferencing again (the `[..]` provides a dereference just as `'*'` does) to reach the 2nd of your allocated poitners.

Comment: I understand the above, makes sense, but don't understand pointer arithmetic here. Say If I do `*ar=malloc(0)`; then this would work `(*(*ar+1)).c = 'c'`, just because I have allocated the first element. So it goes 1 index by size struct Test*. But If I do not initilize the first element, and go directly to lvalue -> `(**(ar+1)).c='c'`, the it goes by size struct 'Test**', but both pointers (first simple pointer, second pointer to pointer) have same size of 8 bytes. So why make difference?

Comment: Why do I add type `struct Test` by `+1` in `(*(*ar+1))`? I though, that by dereferencing `*ar` it is now `pointer-to-Test` ( as you said), so by adding `+1` in `(*(*ar+1))` I would thing I am addting type `pointer-toTest`: `struct Test *` and not ONLY `struct Test`. This `(*ar+1)` is arithmetic in pointers, their object they points to

Comment: You have wrapped us both around the axle with the syntax `:)`. Yes that works. `*ar` is `pointer to struct Test`; `*ar + 1` will `advance to next pointer`; and `*(*ar + 1)` is `struct Test assigned to 2nd pointer` and finally `(*(ar + 1)).c` references `member 'c' of above`

Answer (score 1):

For starters you should correctlyg specify the size of the allocated memory

```
   ar = malloc( 2 * sizeof( struct Test * ) );
```

This statement

```
*(ar+1) = &foo;
```

sets the second element of the allocated array of pointers to the address of the global variable foo.

It is the same as

```
ar[1] = &foo;
```

This expression

```
*ar
```

that is equivalent to the expression

```
ar[0]
```

gives the first element of the allocated array of pointers. It was not initialized. As a result this expression

```
*ar+1
```

or

```
ar[0] + 1
```

invokes undefined behavior (Adding 1 to something that was not initialized and has indeterminate value).

It seems you mean

```
(**(ar+1)).c = 'c';
```

That is the expression

```
*( ar + 1 )
```

gives the second element of the allocated dynamically array of pointers. Dereferencing it you get the address of the object `foo`. Dereferencing the second time you get lvalue of the object foo itself.

Pay attention to that the expression

```
ar[1]
```

is equivalent to

```
*( ar + 1 )
```

and as you can see from this valid statement

```
ar[1]->c = 'c'
```

the above expression yields a pointer. So you need to dereference it if you want to use the operator.

```
**( ar + 1 )
```

Comment: Why do I need to initialize first pointer `*ar`, in order to use the seonc one which IS initialized `(ar+1)=&foo` ?

Comment: @Herdsman You are accessing the first uninitialized pointer in the expression *ar + 1. It is not the same as *( ar + 1 ).

Comment: So i dont have initialize the first element, in order to get to the second one by (**(ar+1)), but if i want to get to the second "throught" the first, I need to initialize the first? Because if so, then i would work

Comment: @Herdsman Please reread one more my answer. I have updated it.

Comment: I understand the above, makes sense, but don't understand pointer arithmetic here. Say If I do `*ar=malloc(8);` then this would work `(*(*ar+1)).c = 'c'`, just because I have allocated the first element. So it goes 1 index by size `struct Test*`. But If I do not initilize the first element, and go directly to lvalue -> `(**(ar+1)).c='c'`, the it goes by size `struct Test**`, but both pointers (first simple pointer, second pointer to pointer) have same size of 8 bytes. So why make difference?

Comment: @Herdsman I have understood nothing.  If you allocated a memory of size 0 you may not set this memory/ What you wrote does not make sense. If you for example set *ar = &foo; Then again *ar + 1 points to memory after the object foo. So writing (*(*ar+1)).c = 'c' again invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: Editted. It really does not matter the size of allocated memory since I just want to get and address (to make the first element initilized) - look at my post, I have editted

Comment: @Herdsman Please, reread my answer one more. There is all written why the expression*( * ( *ar + 1 ) ) is invalid. The expression *ar has no valid value. What is unclear?!

Comment: take a look in my eddited post. It is valid, I do get lvalue by `(*(*ar+1))` just need to initilize the first pointer by `*ar=malloc(0)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213402/discussion-between-vlad-from-moscow-and-herdsman).

Comment: @Herdsman No, it is an invalid code. It has undefined behavior

Answer (score 0):

You want to dereference to get `ar[i]`, let's do as:

```
(*(ar+1))->c = 'c';
```

Comment: your edit `*(ar+1) = &foo;` then `(*(*ar+1)).c = 'c';`. It does not make sense. `*arr+1` is difference to `*(arr+1)`